# Нужно отправить на удалённый компьютер на Win10, cmd'шную команду

Tags: python-3.x, cmd, powershell

В скрипте на python, нужно на удалённом компьютере под управлением Win10 включать и выключать приложение. 
Подскажите пожалуйста какие нибудь способы или инструменты для этого?
(Что то нагуглил пару вариантов, но они какие то переусложнённые и как будто не о том)

Comment: программа TeamViewer вам в этом не сможет помочь ? будет проще.

Comment: [PsExec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

можно воспользоваться модулем [winrm](https://pypi.org/project/pywinrm/0.2.2/)

```
import winrm


# перезапуск службы "Диспетчер печати" на Windows Server 2016
def spooler_restart(server):
    s = winrm.Session(server, auth=(ad_admin, ad_password), transport='ntlm')  # server = dns name
    stop = s.run_cmd('net stop spooler')
    status_stop = stop.std_out.translate(None, b'\r\n').decode('cp866').replace('The ', '').replace('.', '\n')
    time.sleep(1)
    start = s.run_cmd('net start spooler')
    status_start = start.std_out.translate(None, b'\r\n').decode('cp866').replace('The ', '').replace('.', '\n')
```